# Fastest way to subsample sets of columns from large arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, subset, julia

I'm interested in performing statistics on different randomly sampled subsets of a large data matrix, and right now a bottleneck in my code is the actual subsampling.  This seems weird to me, as there's a fair amount of O(N^2) distance calculations on the subsampled data.  I'm not modifying the subsamples at all, just looking at them.

```
using Distributions, Distances

function test_subsetting(X; batch_size=500, nloops=100)
    nfeatures, nsamples = size(X)
    ref_samples = X[:,1:10]
    batch_inds = zeros(batch_size)
    batch = zeros(nfeatures,batch_size)
    d_matrix = zeros(batch_size,batch_size)
    for i = 1:nloops
        batch_inds = sort(sample(1:nsamples, batch_size, replace = false))
        batch = X[:,batch_inds]
        d_matrix = pairwise(SqEuclidean(), batch, ref_samples)
    end
end
```

When I test it out on a 5000 feature by 50000 sample matrix:

```
X_test = randn(5000,50000);
```

I see that I spend about half my time in `_unsafe_getindex` in `multidimensional.jl`, and the other half doing the distance calculation.

Is there a more efficient way to approach this problem?

Comment: If you completely shuffle your matrix X first, and then draw subsequent batches of `n` columns from it (reshuffling it once you get to the end if needed) then that could speed things up.  You could also consider parallelizing things.  This kind of sampling is very amenable to just running this function on multiple workers at once.

Comment: Parallelization is an interesting thought, but the statistics I run on each batch get used to influence the statistics on the next batch in the next round (sorry this isn't clear in my example), so I don't think it parallelizes trivially.  Ideally I'd like to scale this up to things that can't fit in memory, so I don't re-shuffling is the way to go.

Comment: I think I do need to create the `batch`, or maybe a stand-in that doesn't actually allocate new memory for a new array but just keeps the data in `X` and fakes it -- I gather `sub` and `view` do things like this, but I couldn't get them to work with the `pairwise` function from `distances.jl`.

Comment: Re the parallelization - at the very least you could have one process generating your samples and another analyzing them.

Comment: True, that's a good thought.

Comment: I think the problem with subarrays is that a large number of basic operations aren't defined for them.  I haven't studied their structure in detail, but I suspect that if one tried to make such definitions, you'd lose the key features of them in terms of light memory footprint.  You could try posting a separate SO question though just about operations on subarrays.

Comment: No, that's not true. Sometimes it's that packages explicitly declare `A::Array` rather than `A::AbstractArray`. However, with Distances it works for me; perhaps try updating your packages?

Comment: @tholy it looks like `pairwise` works with `view` and `sub` arrays, but I run into trouble when I try to use a 1D array of ints as the column indices, i.e.
`X = rand(500,1000);
S = sample(1:1000,500,replace=false);
M = sub(X,:,S)`
works but then pairwise fails, while
`M = view(X,:,S)`
doens't even create `M`.  Both work fine with pairwise when the indices are something simple like `M = sub(X,:,1:100)`.

Comment: There's some potential for confusion because there's a package called `ArrayViews` which exports `view` (which is much more limited than `sub`), and in julia 0.5 `sub` has been renamed `view`. Make sure you know which you're using.  I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on julia 0.5:

```
julia> using Distances, Distributions

julia> X = randn(500,1000);

julia> S = sample(1:1000,500,replace=false);

julia> M = view(X, :, S);

julia> S2 = sample(1:1000,500,replace=false);

julia> R = view(X, :, S2);

julia> pairwise(SqEuclidean(), M, R)
500×500 Array{Float64,2}:
  994.67 ...
...
```

`view` on julia 0.5 is called `slice` (or `sub`, here they would be the same) on julia 0.4. Not to be confused with `ArrayViews.view`, which does something similar but with a completely different implementation.

Theoretically it seems you should be able to just replace `view` with `slice`, but it seems there's a missing `At_mul_B!` method on julia 0.4. So you may be stuck making a copy.

Comment: I guess it's about time to upgrade to 0.5, then.  Thanks for clarifying the different `view` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can cut your "sampling" time down completely if you are happy to "pre-generate" a nice big matrix of randomised indices that you then just reference at runtime. You can even give that matrix a bit of "rows and columns" shuffling before each use, with minimal cost.

Also, why do you need to sort at all? Surely that defeats the point of random sampling, as well as introducing unnecessary computation?

Comment: I was sorting the samples with the thought that array access might be slightly faster if the columns are in sequential order.  The order of the subsamples doesn't matter, as the statistics performed on them are invariant under permutation.  Using a big pre-generated master list is an interesting thought, but the bottleneck isn't generating the sample _indices_, but rather using those indices to access a subset of the entries in the data matrix.

Comment: It's the `batch = X[:,batch_inds]` line that seems unnecessarily slow -- I was wondering if anyone had thoughts about using `view` or `sub` or something similar.

Comment: @Rory get rid of `sort` then. Sorting is a very costly operation, and you're doing with the intent of achieving a *micro*-optimisation!! Furthermore it's based on a misconception and actually it won't do anything. Julia is column-major-order, roughly meaning that all elements in a single column (i.e. the row elements of that column) are stored contiguously in memory. This means that two elements in the same *row* that are in adjacent *columns*, will actually be quite far apart from each other in terms of memory address. So your sorting "optimisation" would make little difference here.

Comment: @Rory also, I find it extremely unlikely that `batch = X[:,batch_inds]` is the culprit, since if there's anything julia is optimised to do is accessing matrix elements ... if I had to guess, I would say it's perhaps more likely that `batch_inds` is not *actually* evaluated until needed ... thereby that line is where all the sorting and sampling actually takes place. But that's just a guess. If anyone who has better knowledge on how JIT optimisations work could shed some light on this, it would be interesting.
(you *can* test this by drawing your `batch_inds` values from a preexisting matrix)

Comment: But, you're sorting a small set of integers for the indices.  This is very fast.  Breaking up the memory reads of the columns, so that you go back and forth in their ordering when doing the slicing based on non-ordered indices, is going to hit you much harder.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference since they're discontinuous *anyway*. For instance: `a = rand(Int64[0:10;], 100,100);` `b = randperm(100);` `c = collect(1:100);` `d = time(); for n in 1:1000000; sum(a[:,b], 1); end; time() - d`  `e = time(); for n in 1:1000000; sum(a[:,c], 1); end; time() - e`. On my machine, b even takes *less* time than c.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I agree that the sorting might be unnecessary and maybe counterproductive, sorry if that was a distracting aspect of the code sample.  When I profile the (real) code, though, it really doesn't spend any noticeable amount of time on the sampling/sorting, it's all array access.  I'm starting to suspect that it's allocating new memory for `batch` whenever `batch = X[:,batch_inds] ` is run, but I'm not sure how to check this.

Comment: @Rory actually, that's a very good point. That definitely *is* happening. You can check using the `pointer()` function. You will see that batch refers to a new object at a new memory location. If you want to just overwrite the contents of the batch object at the current memory location, you can say `batch[:] = X[:,batch_inds]` instead.